# how to insert multiple data to mysql using checkbox corresponding value?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have been trying to insert multiple values to mysql using checkbox. 
my code goes like this.

```
    <form name='form' method='post'>
    <table>
    <?php
    $id=$_REQUEST['ID'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$id."'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['shapes']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['area']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['characteristic']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    <?php
    }//end whil loop
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="del"/>      
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $select[] = $_POST['select'];
    $select=$_POST['select'];

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($select);$i++){
       $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table2(id, shapes, area, characteristic)
       VALUES('".$select[$i]."', '".$row['shapes']."', 
            '".$row['area']."', '".$row['characteristic']."')");
    }//end for loop
   }
   ?>
```

i was able to correctly insert the checkbox value to table2 but the problem is, those values that go to shapes, area, characteristic fields are not the corresponding values. The values that are being inserted are the values of the last data from table. 
please help. only the checkbox value are being inserted correctly.

Comment: An unclosed quote us there in the last section

Comment: An unclosed quote us there in the last section - i'm sorry but i don't understand.

Comment: @freeloader Look at the code highlighting; notice the color for strings is brown.  Now look af the last 4 lines of code.

Comment: ah, yes..i missed out the closing quote and parenthesis. thanks for pointing that out. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I get it. I have to add a hidden button for the other fields. Thanks.